# Connection between quantum non demolition measurement and the Heisenberg limit in metrology

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurements, metrology, atomic-clocks

Quantum non demolition measurements are those that do not feed back action noise into the measured observable. For discrete systems, this leads to the somewhat trivial case of where the observable (say the population difference, $Z$) commutes with the Hamiltonian:

\begin{align}
\Delta H \Delta Z = \left| \frac{1}{2i} \langle [ H, Z ] \rangle \right| = 0 
\end{align}

The possibility of avoiding back action measurement noise seems to be related to the standard quantum limit of quantum metrology. That is, typically one has some ensemble of two-level systems each in superposition $| \psi \rangle = \prod_i ( \alpha| 0 \rangle + \beta | 1 \rangle)_i$ of $| 0 \rangle, | 1 \rangle$. If the population difference is controlled by some radiation with frequency $\omega$, then in metrology one wishes to estimate this frequency. In particular the frequency variance is given by,
\begin{align}
 ( \Delta \omega)^2 &= \frac{(\Delta Z)^2_{| \psi (\omega) \rangle} }{\left| \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega}\langle Z \rangle \right|^2} \equiv \frac{(\Delta Z)^2_{|\psi (\omega) \rangle}}{\left| \langle \psi(\omega) | [ H, Z ] | \psi (\omega) \rangle \right|^2}
\end{align}

and this scales as $1/\sqrt{N}$ where $N$ is the size of the ensemble, for uncorrelated particles. My question is basically, with the suggestive commutator in the denominator of $(\Delta \omega)^2$, is there a connection between the commutative property of $[H,Z]$ and beating the standard quantum limit of $1/\sqrt{N}$?

Comment: The SQL is usually beat by injecting "designer" states such as NOON states.

Comment: I understand that, and the role of quantum effects like squeezing in reducing noise below the SQL. However since QND is all about avoiding noise, I wondered if there is any connection there. I haven't found anything concrete in the literature.